# What's the best way of using coalesce keyword in Subsonic 2.2 query?

Tags: subsonic, subsonic2.2

I want to create the following query using Subsonic 2.2:

```
SELECT coalesce(col1, col2) AS result
FROM someTable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar to this:

```
DAL.DB.Select(
    string.Format("COALESCE({0}, {2}) as result",
        DAL.SomeTable.Columns.col1,
        DAL.SomeTable.Columns.col2
    ))
.From<DAL.SomeTable>()
...
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up going with. Was just wondering if there was any way of doing it using actual Subsonic properties

Comment: Unfortunately no - sometimes using views can be a workaround, otherwise you'd have to implement it yourself in SubSonic.